# Optaplanner : list of planning variables in one planning entity?

Tags: optaplanner, drools-planner

I am looking into the example use cases from OptaPlanner. And I could not find any similar example which can solve multiple planning variables in one planning entity. For example, in nurse rostering, each `ShiftAssignment(PlanningEntity)` for one shift might require multiple assigned `Employee(PlanningVariables)`. In this case, how can we make use of planner and write rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making the OneToMany side a planning variable, make the ManyToOne side a planning variable. If you have a ManyToMany side, introduce a class between (like in relational database design) and acts as a ManyToOne-OneToMany.

In the nurse rostering example, an example can need 4 nurses on the `Shift` at `ShiftDate` 1-JAN for `ShiftType` Early. In that case, `Shift` has `requiredEmployeeSize` 4, and 4 `ShiftAssignments` are created for that single `Shift`, each with a different `indexInShift`. That way, the `ShiftAssignment` has a planning variable `Employee` which is a ManyToOne relationship, (even though between `Shift` and `Employee` there's a ManyToMany relationship).

Comment: What if the number of employees per shift is something the planner should determine?